# Find frequency of array strings in a file sized string, using Python

Tags: python, regex, arrays, string

I've looked at a lot of answers, which are aimed at finding the occurrence of every word in the file, or big string or even arrays. but I don't want to do this, nor are my strings coming from a text file.

Given a big string, like a file sized string how would you count the frequency of each array element in the big string - including spaces within words?

```
def calculate_commonness(context, links):
    c = Counter()
    content = context.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation).split(None)

    for word in content:
        if word in links:
            c[word] += 1
    print c

context = "It was November. Although it was November November November Passage not yet late, the sky was dark when I turned into Laundress Passage. Father had finished for the day, switched off the shop lights and closed the shutters; but so I would not come home to darkness he had left on the light over the stairs to the flat. Through the glass in the door it cast a foolscap rectangle of paleness onto the wet pavement, and it was while I was standing in that rectangle, about to turn my key in the door, that I first saw the letter. Another white rectangle, it was on the fifth step from the bottom, where I couldn\'t miss it."
links = ['November', 'Laundress', 'Passage', 'Father had']

# My output should look (something) like this:
# November = 4
# Laundress = 1
# Passage = 2
# Father had = 1
```

At the moment it's finding November, Laundress and Passage but not 'Father had'. I need to be able to find string elements with spaces. I know this is because I'm splitting the context by " " which is returning "Father" "had", so how do I split context appropriately or do I use this with regex findall?

EDIT:
Using context as a big string I have:

```
    for l in links:
        c[l] = context.lower().count(l)
    print c
```

returns:

```
Counter({'Laundress': 0, 'November': 0, 'Father had': 0, 'Passage': 0})
```

Comment: What if some of the links are substrings of (concatenation of) others? E.g. `links = ['day', 'mayday', 'today']`.

Comment: Then I shouldn't be counting them. So in that case day should be returned as once. It should match links exactly.

Comment: Maybe I gave a wrong example, what about `links = ['November', 'was November']`? Is the result `{November: 4, was November: 2}` or `{November: 2, was November: 2}`?

Comment: In that case it would be the second set of results. November: 2, was November 2. 
This is counting how many times a term, being one word or multiple is being used as a link to somewhere specific in a document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
context.lower()
counts = {word: context.count(word)
          for word in links}
```

Note: leave `context` as a string.

Comment: This is just test strings for a bigger project, so doing that means I would have to go through my database, and manually type each link that has multiple words.

Comment: No, you don't have to do it manually, that was just an example. I've updated my answer for a fuller demo.

Comment: I managed to get that to work better than what I had! But for every term in link it's returning 0. I've added an edit.

Comment: Yes, because you still have upper case in your links. If case is important, remove `lower()`, otherwise make your links all lower case.

Comment: According to the comments under the OP, this works, but counts the substrings multiple times, which is not an expected result.

Comment: Yes, but they've accepted it! Not sure we yet have enough context to give a really good answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
>>> import re
>>> for word in links:
    print word+ '=' + str(len([w.start() for w in re.finditer(word, context)]))


November=4
Laundress=1
Passage=2
Father had=1
>>>
```

you can use ignore case also

```
 for word in links:
         print word+ '=' + str(len([w.start() for w in re.finditer(word, context, re.IGNORECASE)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a implementation using regex findall.

```
import re
links = ['November', 'Laundress', 'Passage', 'Father had']
# Create a big regex catching all the links 
# Something like: "(November)|(Laundress)|(Passage)|(Father had)"
regex = "|".join(map(lambda x: "(" + x + ")", links))

context = "It was November. Although it was November November November Passage not yet late, the sky was dark when I turned into Laundress Passage. Father had finished for the day, switched off the shop lights and closed the shutters; but so I would not come home to darkness he had left on the light over the stairs to the flat. Through the glass in the door it cast a foolscap rectangle of paleness onto the wet pavement, and it was while I was standing in that rectangle, about to turn my key in the door, that I first saw the letter. Another white rectangle, it was on the fifth step from the bottom, where I couldn\'t miss it."

result = re.findall(regex, context)
# Result here is:
# [('November', '', '', ''), ('November', '', '', ''), ('November', '', '', ''), ('November', '', '', ''), ('', '', 'Passage', ''), ('', 'Laundress', '', ''), ('', '', 'Passage', ''), ('', '', '', 'Father had')]

# Now we count regex matches
counts = [0] * len(links)
for x in result:
    for i in range(len(links)):
        if not x[i] == "":
             counts[i] += 1
```